# Unable find model com.liferay.bookmarks.model.impl.BookmarksEntryImpl

Tags: java, exception, liferay-7

I have been trying to deploy bookmark portlet in liferay-7.0dxp, but this error occurs everytime:

```
 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-7][DynamicQueryFactoryImpl:107] Unable find model com.liferay.bookmarks.model.impl.BookmarksEntryImpl
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.bookmarks.model.impl.BookmarksEntryImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.getImplClass(DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.getImplClass(DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.java:95)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.forClass(DynamicQueryFactoryImpl.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.java:31)
    at be.aca.lifedash.bookmarks.service.impl.DefaultBookmarkService.getGroupBookmarks(DefaultBookmarkService.java:150)
    at be.aca.lifedash.bookmarks.bean.ViewBookmarkBean.initBookmarks(ViewBookmarkBean.java:149)
    at be.aca.lifedash.bookmarks.bean.ViewBookmarkBean.init(ViewBookmarkBean.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2006.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
```

Please help me in understanding what does this exception mean and how can it be resolved.

Comment: You need to have  a line in your project Gradle file similar to: implementation 'com.liferay.bookmarks.service:1.1.19'. Or else copy the .jar file into the your-project/libs directory and update the Gradle file to use it. [com.liferay.bookmarks.service](https://www.findjar.com/jar/com/liferay/com.liferay.bookmarks.service/1.1.19/com.liferay.bookmarks.service-1.1.19.jar.html)

Comment: Thanks for explaining it even more clearly. And as per your suggestion i did added 'com.liferay.bookmarks.service:1.1.19 ' dependency, since i am using maven so i added it in pom.xml,but still i am facing same error.

Comment: Looks like the missing class is in this lib:[BookmarksEntry](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.liferay.portal/release.portal.api/7.1.1/source-code/com/liferay/bookmarks/model/BookmarksEntry.java)